# Including external .js files for unit tests

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, tdd, qunit

I am trying to run coverage tests for my JavaScript unit tests (written in QUnit [not my idea, legacy project]) and run them via command line.
Problem i am facing is references to external bits of code.
Look at example bellow:

Code:

```
var DateHelper = function() {
return {
    GetUtcDate: function (date) {
            if (DateTypeChecker.Data["date"]) {
                return new Date();
            }
            return date;
    }
}
```

Test:

```
QUnit.test('GetUtcNow - compare UTC date', function(assert) {
  var currentUtcDate = DateHelper.GetUtcNow();
  var nowDate = new Date();

  assert.equal(nowDate.getUTCFullYear() == currentUtcDate.getFullYear(), 'dates are the same');
});
```

So a very simple test that checks two dates, this works lovely when run in the browser, because the external javascript file containing `DateTypeChecker` is loaded in the HEAD.
But this test fails in the command line as `node` (or w/e is performing the test) doesn't have a reference to `DateTypeChecker` object.

My question is, how do i fix this, so that the file for `DateTypeChecker` is loaded/required? (i know that i can do this with RequireJS, but i don't wan't to add more dependencies and frameworks)

I think this is a general question for `js` unit testing (not just QUnit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options: (a) mock out the external dependency or (b) actually include the external dependency JS file. For the second option (b), I would use a test runner like Karma and [hook up QUnit](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-qunit) to it. The configuration is pretty straight forward on that linked site.

The first option (a) is what I would recommend, however. It makes your tests more idempotent and thus loosely coupled. In QUnit you can set up a mock pretty easy, we just use a simple beforeEach function:

```
QUnit.module( "testing DateHelper", {
  beforeEach: function() {
    // before each test runs, we can create a "fake" DateTypeChecker
    // Note that it doesn't matter what this thing does, so long as it 
    // satisfies your dependency in the DateHelper
    window.DateTypeCheker = {
      Data: { date: true }
    };
  }
});

QUnit.test( ... ); // your normal stuff
```

Comment: Excellent answer, i haven't considered option a) at all, as some of the external object literals are quite large, i'll try it :)
Answer b) i already considered along side RequireJS and similar methods, but since that would also require fiddling about on the live server of the project i didin't want to bother with it.

Comment: **Answer a) worked.**
But i would recommend you edit your answer as the `window` object doesn't need to be referenced at all.
Cheers.

Comment: I'm glad it worked! As for the `window` object, any time you define anything outside of a function in JavaScript that thing is placed on the global scope... in browsers that is `window`. Your "real" DateTypeChecker *must* be on the `window` object in order for you to use it in another file. In fact, if you _didn't_ use window here and tried to use `var DateTypeChecker = {...}` it would **not** work since that variable would only be defined inside the `beforeEach` function. I **highly recommend keeping this as `window.DateTypeChecker`**.